# How to proceed with `None` value in pandas fillna

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dictionary:

`fillna(value={'first_name':'Andrii', 'last_name':'Furmanets', 'created_at':None})`

When I pass that dictionary to `fillna` I see:

> raise ValueError('must specify a fill method or value')\nValueError: must specify a fill method or value\n"

It seems to me that it fails on `None` value.

I use pandas version 0.20.3.

Comment: in a float column, None is de-facto represented by np.nan (and in most types). So this doesn't make any sense. see the docs here from https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10871

Comment: `d= {'first_name': 'Andrii', 'last_name':'Furmanets'}`

Comment: The dictionary comes from outside and must go through the pandas, there is created_at field,  it seems to me that it worked with pandas 0.18.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What type of data structure are you using? This works for a pandas Series:

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.Series({'first_name': 'Andrii', 'last_name':'Furmanets', 'created_at':None})
d = d.fillna('DATE')
```

Comment: I use Dictionary not String.

Comment: What are you attempting to replace `None` with?

Comment: It could be even `"None"` .

Comment: I normalize dict before put into `fillna`. As you have mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 95):

In case you want to normalize all of the nulls with python's None.

```
df.fillna(np.nan).replace([np.nan], [None])
```

The first `fillna` will replace all of (None, NAT, np.nan, etc) with Numpy's NaN, then replace Numpy's NaN with python's None.

Comment: To me, this was the most simple way to apply None to entire dataframe.

Comment: `df.replace([np.nan], [None])` this is sufficient

Comment: @mangusta For most cases you're right, but If you have other types of null (e.g. pd.NaT) you won't necessarily get python's None after `replace`. Starting with `fillna` is more consistent.

Comment: Can someone explain why this works? In my case, I was using only `.replace({np.nan: None})` and not `.fillna()`. I wanted to turn all nan values to None but sometimes I had perfect DF where there were no nan, only some None values, but `.replace()` turned all None to nan when it was supposed to do the opposite?

Comment: Very useful when using xlwings, which doesn't support `NA`s, but supports `None`s.

Comment: Why are the list brackets necessary?

Comment: For my own specific case, I used this two-steps way following the answer: `df = df.fillna('').replace([''], [None])` and it is okay for me because I also want the empty strings to be None.

Comment: @michen00 I believe the brackets are necessary because `None` passed as `value` is not interpreted as value to actually set in the df but as "default" and the default must be to set to `np.nan`, which leads to a recursion issue: NaN replaced with Nan replaced with Nan,...

Comment: what about using pd.NA instead?

Answer (score 23):

**Setup**
Consider the sample dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, None], B=[None, 2], C=[None, 'D']))

df

     A    B     C
0  1.0  NaN  None
1  NaN  2.0     D
```

I can confirm the error

```
df.fillna(dict(A=1, B=None, C=4))
```

> ```
> ValueError: must specify a fill method or value
> ```

This happens because pandas is cycling through keys in the dictionary and executing a `fillna` for each relevant column.  If you look at the signature of the [**`pd.Series.fillna`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) method

> ```
> Series.fillna(value=None, method=None, axis=None, inplace=False, limit=None, downcast=None, **kwargs)
> ```

You'll see the default value is `None`.  So we can replicate this error with

```
df.A.fillna(None)
```

Or equivalently

```
df.A.fillna()
```

I'll add that I'm not terribly surprised considering that you are attempting to fill a null value with a null value.

---

What you need is a work around

**Solution**
Use [**`pd.DataFrame.fillna`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) over columns that you want to fill with non-null values.  Then follow that up with a [**`pd.DataFrame.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) on the specific columns you want to swap one null value with another.

```
df.fillna(dict(A=1, C=2)).replace(dict(B={np.nan: None}))

     A     B  C
0  1.0  None  2
1  1.0     2  D
```

Comment: I `value` as parameter in `fillna`, like this: `df.fillna(value=dict(A=1, B=None, C=4))`

Comment: Is it the same?

Comment: Yes.  It is the same.

Comment: For me ('1.0.3') `df.fillna(value=dict(A=1, B=None, C=4))` blows with the same ValueError.

Comment: "you are attempting to fill a null value with a null value." very very wrong conclusion. None is different than Not A Number. `None or ''` return `''` but `np.nan or ''` returns `np.nan`. Try to perform some string operation on that now.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method to fillna with `None`. I am on pandas `0.24.0` and I am doing this to insert NULL values to POSTGRES database.

```
# Stealing @pIRSquared dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, None], B=[None, 2], C=[None, 'D']))

df

     A    B     C
0  1.0  NaN  None
1  NaN  2.0     D

# fill NaN with None. Basically it says, fill with None whenever you see NULL value.
df['A'] = np.where(df['A'].isnull(), None, df['A'])
df['B'] = np.where(df['B'].isnull(), None, df['B'])

# Result
df

     A    B     C
0  1.0  None  None
1  None  2.0     D
```

Comment: `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`  Unfortunately, I can't give the example because they are very large dataframes with sensitive data.  Any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:** use pandas `pd.NA` not base Python `None`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first_name':pd.NA, 'last_name':pd.NA, 'created_at':pd.NA}, index=[0])

df = df.fillna(value={'first_name':'Andrii', 'last_name':'Furmanets', 'created_at':pd.NA})
```

Generally it's better to leave pandas `NA` as-is. Do not try to change it. The presence of NA is a feature, not an issue. `NA` gets handled correctly in other pandas functions (but not numpy)

- If you insist that python None should replace pandas NA's for some downstream reason, show us the missing code that follows where NA is causing an issue; that's usually an XY problem.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson: this absolutely is an answer (leave the NaT as is, do not replace it), is [recommended by the pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#datetimes) and in most situations avoids problems down the line, pandas functions are NaT-aware. The OP hasn't shown any downstream code where NaT is actually causing an issue. I edited the answer to add that explanation.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson: then NA, not NaT. This is very much still the right answer: NaN's are generally your friend in pandas and work in aggregations, joins etc. The OP still hasn't shown any downstream code where NA is actually causing an issue, hence this is an XY question: just bwcause they insist they need to fillna, doesn't mean they need to.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson: NA, NaN (and NaT) are fully pandas-compatible values; whereas base Python `None` isn't. That's the bottom line and what I've been consistently saying for 4 years. Look at the pandas doc, they don't recommend using `None` as idiomatic pandas.

Comment: what does pd.NA get written to if you were to do a to_csv?

Comment: @mike01010 `.to_csv()` writes it out the same as NaN or None; and that is determined by the setting `na_rep`, which defaults to empty string ('').

Comment: then i dont know why this answer was downvoted. it actually was the solution i used before actaully googling and finding this post.  this post made me question my use of it...but clearly it seems like a viable and simple solution.